# Inside div my scroll bar is showing but can't use it (not working)

Tags: php, html, css

[image]

```css
#smry {
    background-color: #1AB294;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 5px auto auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="smry">
    <h2>Current Account Details</h2><br>

    <?php 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM username "; 
        $accdtl = mysql_query($sql); 
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($accdtl))
        { 
            echo '<table>
             <tr width="100%"><td width="15%">User-Name</td><td width="15%" >Password</td><td width="10%">Type</td></tr>
             <tr width="100%"><td width="15%" >'.$row['userName']; echo'</td><td width="15%" >'.$row['pass'];echo'</td><td width="10%" >'.$row['type'];echo'</td></tr>
             </table>';
            echo '<br>';
        };
    ?>
</div>
```

All other things are working but can't use the scroll bar although it's displaying? I can't understand the problem.

Comment: What is your css on `div` to the right of `<div id="smry">`? Could be that `div` is overlapping the scroll bar.

Comment: Could we have an example out of the final HTML code instead of that snippet, please? It's hard to know what your problem is - that snippet does not reproduce it.

Comment: u mena you wanna full code is it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to be very difficult to try and diagnose this without being able to see what the php returns.

Throwing the bits into a fiddle and adding some junk data I get [this](http://jsfiddle.net/m0L91fcL/), which works fine.

```
<div id="smry">
    <h2>Current Account Details</h2>
    <br>

    <table>
        <tr width="100%"><td width="15%">User-Name</td><td width="15%" >Password</td><td width="10%">Type</td></tr>

        <tr width="100%"><td width="15%" >asdasd</td><td width="15%" >asdasd</td><td width="10%" >asdas</td></tr><tr width="100%"><td width="15%" >asdasd</td><td width="15%" >asdasd</td><td width="10%" >asdas</td></tr><tr width="100%"><td width="15%" >asdasd</td><td width="15%" >asdasd</td><td width="10%" >asdas</td></tr><tr width="100%"><td width="15%" >asdasd</td><td width="15%" >asdasd</td><td width="10%" >asdas</td></tr><tr width="100%"><td width="15%" >asdasd</td><td width="15%" >asdasd</td><td width="10%" >asdas</td></tr><tr width="100%"><td width="15%" >asdasd</td><td width="15%" >asdasd</td><td width="10%" >asdas</td></tr><tr width="100%"><td width="15%" >asdasd</td><td width="15%" >asdasd</td><td width="10%" >asdas</td></tr><tr width="100%"><td width="15%" >asdasd</td><td width="15%" >asdasd</td><td width="10%" >asdas</td></tr><tr width="100%"><td width="15%" >asdasd</td><td width="15%" >asdasd</td><td width="10%" >asdas</td></tr><tr width="100%"><td width="15%" >asdasd</td><td width="15%" >asdasd</td><td width="10%" >asdas</td></tr><tr width="100%"><td width="15%" >asdasd</td><td width="15%" >asdasd</td><td width="10%" >asdas</td></tr><tr width="100%"><td width="15%" >asdasd</td><td width="15%" >asdasd</td><td width="10%" >asdas</td></tr><tr width="100%"><td width="15%" >asdasd</td><td width="15%" >asdasd</td><td width="10%" >asdas</td></tr><tr width="100%"><td width="15%" >asdasd</td><td width="15%" >asdasd</td><td width="10%" >asdas</td></tr><tr width="100%"><td width="15%" >asdasd</td><td width="15%" >asdasd</td><td width="10%" >asdas</td></tr><tr width="100%"><td width="15%" >asdasd</td><td width="15%" >asdasd</td><td width="10%" >asdas</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>

#smry {
    background-color: #1AB294;
    width: 400px;
    height:300px;
    float:left;
    margin : 5px 5px auto auto;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: i posted image about resut

Comment: yah i found this issue bcz of my css sheet may b cz it i cant add a href links too same issue its appear but not working if i unlink css file its working well